# Oracle datatype for C# storing stack trace

Tags: c#, oracle, stack-trace

I would like to know which Oracle datatype is ideal for storing exception stack trace coming from C# code.

Comment: The Stack Trace coming from a C# exception is a string, a fairly large one.  Pick your Oracle data type accordingly.

Comment: You can use `CLOB` for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Exception.StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) gets a string representation of the immediate frames on the call stack with type System.String.

If you are interested in the full trace it may not fit in to the [VARCHAR2 variable which has a limit of 4000 bytes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm), you would have to use the [CLOB datatype which stores up to 128 terabytes of character data](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1835).

A clob will be stored inline as a varchar2 up to 4000 bytes so there won't be any performance difference. When it exceeds that ,it will be moved out of line which will be slow to access.

So if you are concerned about performance you might also look into storing only part of the full trace. For example, the first line which has the actual error, and the line where your own code calls the framework code.

Answer (score 0):

Use CLOB type to store large text (Character) data.

Comment: That should do to my knowledge.